# How do I pass object(list) to string(list) - Terraform

Tags: terraform, hcl

I want to pass a list with 2 objects to **lambda_name** as an array variable, lambda_name must receive **my_app and my_app_2 key name**, example:

```
variable "lambda" {
  type = object({
    my_app = object({
      name = string
    })
    my_app_2 = object({
      name = string
    })
  })
  description = "Lambda Function required values"
}
```

```
data "external" "lambdas" {
    program = ["bash", "scripts/random.sh"]

    query = {
        lambda_name  = (["${var.lambda.my_app.name}", "${var.lambda.my_app_2.name}"])
        environment = var.environment
    }
}
```

The error i got:

> Inappropriate value for attribute "query": element "lambda_name":
> string required.

Comment: These cannot be a `list(string)` either. They need to be the primitive `string` type because the `query` map must be serialized as a JSON formatted string. I think you can maybe `jsonencode` it and it will not be corrupted when it is doubly JSON formatted, but I am not certain.

Comment: Assuming you mean the values inside the `query` block, it should indeed be possible to serialize them as JSON using `jsonencode`. The caveat is that the external program will receive it as a JSON string _containing more JSON_, and so it'll need to first parse the top-level JSON it receives on `stdin` and then parse the JSON inside the nested property value, which in a shell script will require two consecutive calls to `jq`, or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
data "external" "lambdas" {
    program = ["bash", "scripts/random.sh"]

    query = {
        lambda_name = "${var.lambda.my_app.name} ${var.lambda.my_app_2.name}"
        environment = var.environment
    }
}
```

on **scripts/random.sh**, i'm using lambda_name as array variable.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

eval "$(jq -r '@sh "export LAMBDA_NAME=\(.lambda_name)"')"

for lambda in ${LAMBDA_NAME[@]}; do echo $lambda; done
```